# How to understand IN DEPTH gcc compiler?

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-construction

Background of this question : I am trying to understand how compilers work. I learn many new things : scanner, parser, AST, IR, optimisation, frontend, backend,LL(1), ... I made gradual progress and it is very interesting. Now, I would like to do some practical works.
From a programmer point of view, I know why `typedef struct { int x; mytype* next; } mytype;` does not compile and I know the correct syntax `typedef struct mystruct { int x; struct mystruct* next; } mytype;` but I would like to know where the problem happens **EXACTLY** during compilation. I am using gcc, I would like to know how is it posible to use gcc developper options **-fdump-...** to answer this question.

Comment: What do you mean by `where the problem happens EXACTLY during compilation`? The C language standard mandates an error and the compiler implements it. Do you need to know which line of which file in gcc does it? Or what are you asking?

Comment: It's definitely not in the lexer, backend or any of the many optimizers. It's early on somewhere around the frontend.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze. You write _somewhere around the frontend_, this is exactly what I would like to know  (Rq . `typedef struct ...` is only an example to illustrate what I try to do but I have others). I wonder if there is some strategy with developer options (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options)  to understand where it happens exactly if you look in the files that are generated (.tu, .original, .gimple, .omplower and so on ...). For info : I start to read the dragon book.

Comment: Clearly, the dragon book won't tell you anything specific about gcc. What you may do is find where the error gets printed from and then work backwards from there.

Comment: @Alexey. I agree Dragon book is a general book. If I want to do what I asked in the question, it is to do something else than theory. Theory (as explained in Dragon book) is very interesting but very difficult to understand. Fortunately, there are many documentations on the web to help me. So, I would like to use gcc and -fdump options to do pratical works. I have two objectives :  try to get my head around some points and also  relax me :). I know you write a compiler : congratulations !!! and perhaps you have some advices to give me for my understanding compilation journey.

Comment: If you're interested in the inner workings of gcc, you may as well try asking your questions on their mailing list(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step of the GCC compiler work is parser

```
c-parser.c
```

It parse your c or c++ or some else code into gimple representation:

```
Parse -> Gimplify -> Tree -> SSA -> Optimize -> Generate -> RTL -> Optimize RTL Generate -> ASM
```

Errors can be found, for example, in terminal, or in IDE in error output like next:

```
gcc yourcode.c
yourcode.c:2:25: error: unknown type name 'mytype'
 typedef struct { int x; mytype* next; } mytype;
                         ^~~~~~
```

You also can look at how it works via a
[link](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c)

Sorry for my English.